# Split columns by vs. in dataframe and get 2 columns as results

Tags: python

[image]

I am trying to split a column into two columns:

My dataframe looks like:

**First table**

```
Value   
4 vs. 6
4 vs. 7 
1 vs. 3
5 
6 vs. 5
6
3
```

I want to split Value column by vs. :

I tried:

```py
dataframe[['Today', 'Yesterday']] = dataframe["Value"].str.split("vs.", expand=True)
```

I have the following output:

```
Value        
4 vs. 6         
4 vs. 7            
1 vs. 3      
5           
6 vs. 5      
6            
3

Today
4
4
1
0
6
0
0

Yesterday
6
7
3
0
5
0
0
```

I would not expect 0 values when there's no vs.

What I want is:

**Third table**

```
Value        
4 vs. 6         
4 vs. 7            
1 vs. 3      
5           
6 vs. 5      
6            
3            

Today
4
4
1
5
6
6
3

Yesterday
6 
7 
3 
5 
5 
6 
3
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
dataframe["Value"]=dataframe["Value"].apply(lambda x: x+'vs.'+x if 'vs.' not in x else x)
dataframe[['Today', 'Yesterday']] = dataframe["Value"].str.split("vs.", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
// your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(["4 vs. 6", "4 vs. 7", "1 vs. 3","5", "6 vs. 5", "6", "3"], columns=["values"])

def getToday(string):
    if "vs" in string:
        return string.split("vs.")[0].strip()
    else:
        return string.strip()

def getYesterday(string):
    if "vs" in string:
        return string.split("vs.")[1].strip()
    else:
        return string.strip()

df["yesterday"] = df["values"].apply(getYesterday)

df["today"] = df["values"].apply(getToday)
```